# How to use object into assigning in guid

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 public JsonResult SaveTimeSheet(Guid TimesheetID, List<TaskHours> TaskHours)
    {
     TimeSheet timeSheet = new TimeSheet();
     TimeSheetData timesheetdata = new TimeSheetData();
      timesheetdata.TimeSheet = TimesheetID;
   }
```

getting this error:

> cannot implicitly convert system guid to TSM.Models.TimeSheets.TimeSheet

i want to take Guid TimesheetID object in timesheetdata.TimeSheet by assign

```
public class TimeSheetData 
{ 
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public Guid ID { get; set;}
    public double Hours { get; set;} 
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } 
    public Guid TaskID { get; set; } 
    public virtual TimeSheet TimeSheet { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: timesheetdata.TimeSheet is a guid

Comment: TimeSheetData(guid id,Date,Hours,guid TimeSheet),,,TimeSheets(StartDate,EndDate,GuidID)

Comment: Would you share TimeSheet class ?

Comment: And can you paste the EXACT error please

Comment: error is ::cannot implicitly convert system guid to TSM.Models.TimeSheets.TimeSheet

Comment: I only count 36 characters if you count the `-` a standard Guid has 38 can you edit it and try the following 
`"{ECBAA703-DAD9-E711-9666-000C297C9306}"`

Comment: Timesheet is its own type it is not a Guid

Comment: i want to save timesheet data which include timesheetid but i am not added in tImeSheets table. i mean one timesheet have multiple timesheet data

Comment: its list of timesheet

Comment: then what i do.

Answer (score 2):

The type Guid in your timesheet is not System.Guid. You have to choose whether to use System.Guid or your own defined Guid.

Comment: i did'nt get you@Rawitas krungKaew